# QueryTables on non-ActiveSheet range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been putting `QueryTables` results in the `ActiveSheet`, but now I want to put them off to the side in a different sheet.  In the following code the commented out line is what I had originally, the following "with" line is my new attempt.

```
Dim QuerySheet As WorkSheet

Dim ttt As Integer
Set QuerySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ZZ$Temp$")
QuerySheet.Cells.Clear

QuerySheet.Cells(1, 1) = 1234
QuerySheet.Cells(2000, 50) = 5678

ttt = QuerySheet.Cells(1, 1)

' With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range(Cells(row_stock + iMax, 27), Cells(row_stock + iMax + 199, 27)))
With QuerySheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=QuerySheet.Range(Cells(row_stock + iMax, 27), Cells(row_stock + iMax + 199, 27)))
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
```

I know the sheet exists and I define contents at `1, 1` and `2000, 50`.

I get the error `Run-time error '1004' Method 'Range of object '_worksheet' failed.`

I also tried activating `QuerySheet` and with the original `With`.

How do I get `QueryTables` to put stuff in `QuerySheet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set QuerySheet somewhere. Simply `Dim` is not enough. Add

```
 Dim QuerySheet As WorkSheet
 set QuerySheet = Sheets("querysheet")
```

(or whatever the name of the sheet is) is before your code.

Then, you will have to change the following to only reference QuerySheet (all "cells" and "range" uses that are applicable to the QuerySheet).

```
With QuerySheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=QuerySheet.Range(QuerySheet.Cells(row_stock + iMax, 27), QuerySheet.Cells(row_stock + iMax + 199, 27)))
```

Comment: Please update the question with all relevant code if you still are getting the error.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That works and is certainly better than the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works.  Yes, all the Sheets references are required!

```
With Sheets("ZZ$Temp$").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets("ZZ$Temp$").Range(Sheets("ZZ$Temp$").Cells(row_stock + iMax, 27), Sheets("ZZ$Temp$").Cells(row_stock + iMax + 199, 27)))
```